# Why does my view keep giving a 404 error?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-views

I'm using Django 1.4 with Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.04.

I've written many views before but I'm a bit baffled as to why I'm getting a 404 error on this one.

urls.py:

```
url(r'^addNewClient/', 'gateway_interface.views.add_new_client'),
```

views.py

```
def add_new_client(request):
    """
    ..  function:: add_new_client()

        Provide a form for entering new client information

        :param request: Django Request object
    """
    ## Create a logging object
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'logs/')
    filename = '{0}addNewClient.log'.format(path)
    logfile = open(filename, 'a')
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    logfile.write('\n --------------------- {0}\n'.format(now))

    try:
        form = addClientInfo()
    except:
        output = "Handle Error: Cannot create a valid form"
        logfile.write('{0}\n'.format(output))
        logfile.write('{0}\n\n'.format(traceback.format_exc()))
        logfile.close()
        return HttpResponse(output)

    try:
        data = {}
        data.update(csrf(request))
        data.update({ 'form' : form })
    except:
        output = "Handle Error: Cannot generate CSRF token"
        logfile.write('{0}\n'.format(output))
        logfile.write('{0}\n\n'.format(traceback.format_exc()))
        logfile.close()
        return HttpResponse(output)

    return render_to_response("addNewClientInfo.html", data)
```

forms.py

```
class addClientInfo(forms.Form):
    """
    ..  class:: addClientInfo

        Create a form to enter new client info
    """
    my_gateway_choices = tuple(gateway_proper_names.items())

    # Create the post fields
    tkz_client_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 50, required = True)
    tkz_gateway = forms.ChoiceField(widget = forms.Select(), choices = my_gateway_choices, required = True)
    tkz_gateway_api_id = forms.CharField(max_length = 50, required = True)
    tkz_gateway_trans_key = forms.CharField(max_length = 50, required = True)
    tkz_ys_api_id = forms.CharField(max_length = 50, required = True)
    tkz_ys_trans_key = forms.CharField(max_length = 50, required = True)
```

Any thoughts?

EDIT1:

I should mention I am not receiving any info in the error log.  The .html file exists along with all my other templates...in the same place.

Comment: What url you trying to access and what you do get on 404 page? Is `DEBUG=True` in your settings?

Comment: Jeez...this is why you don't start working at 3am.  I forgot to import the form I'm trying to generate.  Newb mistake!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I put the `DEBUG=True` the exceptions where thrown and I was able to determine that I did not import the form I'm trying use: `addClientInfo()`.

Very newb of me.  The difficulty is that the error I received didn't seem to point to this as a problem.  Hopefully others can see that misleading errors may have underlying problems that aren't immediately obvious.

Best, all!

Answer (score 1):

Usually urls patterns have to be very precise. Try using the following url pattern for the view:

```
url(r'^addNewClient/$', 'gateway_interface.views.add_new_client'),
```

That pattern ensures that only `addnewClinet/` will match by using `$`. Otherwise the url pattern only matches the beginning of the string, not the whole string, so things like `addNewClient/foo` will also match.